# Database benchmarking: should the data transfer/protocol latency be included?

Tags: c#, mongodb, postgresql, benchmarking

I am currently benchmarking two databases, Postgres and MongoDB, on a relatively large data set with equivalent queries. Of course, I am doing my best to put them on equal grounds, but I have one dilemma. For Postgres I take the execution time reported by `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, and there is a similar concept with MongoDB, using profiling (although not equivalent, `millis`).

However, different times are observed if executed from, lets say, PgAdmin or the `mongo` CLI client or in my watched C# app. That time also includes the transfer latency, and probably protocol differences. PgAdmin, for example, actually seems to completely deform the execution time (it obviously includes the result rendering time).

The question is: is there any sense in actually measuring the time on the "receiving end", since an application actually does consume that data? Or does it just include too many variables and does not contribute anything to the actual database performance, and I should stick to the reported DBMS execution times?

Answer (score 0):

The question you'd have to answer is why are you benchmarking the databases?  If you are benchmarking so you can select one over the other, for use in a C# application, then you need to measure the time "on the 'receiving end'".  Whatever variables that may contain, that is what you need to compare.